# Finding values with partial data in another worksheet - Excel

Tags: excel, function, formula, worksheet

I would like to find similar data in another worksheet from partial data.

I have two worksheets - 1 contains column of data (some partial serial numbers) and would like to find similar or match or that contains some of the data in sheet 1 from a second worksheet and list the 'finds' on 1st worksheet.

***The partial I have in sheet one, I want to find in sheet 2 which is the full serial...meaning if I have B002345 in sheet one, I want to find 371000-B002345 in shee 2 and return the full serial in sheet 1.***

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: try to use **VLOOKUP** function. If won't be sufficient you need to add more information to your question.

Comment: I used the following but it only returned exact matches: =INDEX(Lookup!F:F,MATCH(B3&"*",Lookup!F:F,0))

Comment: Experiment with both `True` and `False` value of last function argument.

Comment: Thanks, True returns anything it find a match on, even one digit, False looks for an exact match...I guess this is too much...lol..thanks anyway...

Comment: The partial I have in sheet one, I want to find in sheet 2 which is the full serial...meaning if I have B002345 in sheet one, I want to find 371000-B002345 in shee 2 and return the full serial in sheet 1.

Comment: Antything further KazJaw?

Comment: your match is missing a crucial piece `=INDEX(Lookup!F:F,MATCH("*"&B3&"*",Lookup!F:F,0))`

Comment: Yes!!! Thank you...that worked...completely missed that...

Comment: @pnuts seems a bit late now?

Answer (score 0):

your match is/was missing a crucial piece

```
=INDEX(Lookup!F:F,MATCH("*"&B3&"*",Lookup!F:F,0))
```